# How to remove metadata labels added by Docker Task in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines

When building a docker image in Azure Pipelines the Docker Task adds traceability related metadata to the image in the form of the following labels:

- com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.uri
- com.azure.dev.image.build.repository.name
- com.azure.dev.image.build.sourcebranchname
- com.azure.dev.image.build.sourceversion
- com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri
- com.azure.dev.image.system.teamproject
- com.azure.dev.image.build.definitionname
- com.azure.dev.image.build.buildnumber
- com.azure.dev.image.build.requestedfor

I don't want this metadata in my public docker image.

How can I prevent Azure Pipelines from adding metadata to my images?
Or how do I remove those labels from the image built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the source code for the DockerV2 Azure Pipelines command I have figured this out.

There is a Boolean parameter 'addPipelineData'. 
(See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DockerV2/dockerbuild.ts)

Setting 'addPipelineData: false' removes most of the metadata labels:

```
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build image
    inputs:
      command: build
      addPipelineData: false
...
```

Though, it looks like there is no way to remove 'teamfoundationcollectionuri' label.